# Use a custom operator in a different file

Tags: swift

I have a newly created operator `?=`:

```
    infix operator ?= {}
    func ?=<T>(inout lhs: T?, rhs: T) {
        if lhs == nil {
            lhs = rhs
        }
    }
```

This is declared in some `utils.swift` file, in the global scope of that file.
Then, I try to use the newly created operator in some class function inside another file:

```
imageView.image ?= avatarDefault
```

Basically I want to set `avatarDefault` to `imageView.image` only if it's currently `nil`...
This causes a compile error: `Operator is not a known binary operator`

When I try to declare it again in the same file (`infix operator ?= {}`) but still keeping the other declaration and the `func` in `utils.swift` - it compiles, and works...

My question is - why can't I declare the operator in a file (i.e., `utils.swift`) and then use it throughout the app?

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom operators through different files, what you probably miss is adding `utils.swift` to build target when you created utils file. To fix this go to project Build Phases and add `utils.swift` to Compile Sources

Comment: I did have it and I even tried to drag it to the top of the list there... Didn't help... do you know of any way to force build `utils` first?

Comment: Try removing it, build your project (comment the line when custom operator is used so it builds succefully) then add it again

Comment: @AvielGross This issue looks strange since I just tried it and its working fine for me. Can you create a variable inside `utils.swift` and try to access it?

Comment: `utils.swift` has many more global functions and extensions, all of them are used throughout the project with no problem... So I don't think it's a problem with accessing the file

Comment: any success on this?